# How to delete memory usage during an Experiment?

Tags: anylogic

I am constructing an experiment in Anylogic, which saves data in the Parameter variation tab under a `custom-class` list. The model needs to perform a lot of simulations, and repetitions to optimize for Setting variables in the model itself. After x amount of iterations, I use a Python connector to run some code in finding new possible parameters for the underlaying model.

The problem I am having right now, is that around Simulation-run number 200, the memory usage is maximum (4Gb), and it proceeds to run super-slow. I have found some interesting ways to cut on memory usage, but I believe there is only one thing that could help me right now: let the system delete memory that is used for past iterations. After each iteration, the data of a simulation is stored, so I am fine with anylogic deleting the logs of the specific simulation afterwards.

Is such a thing possible? If so, how can I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

Java makes use of a [Garbage collector](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/garbage-collection-java/) to manage memory usage and you have no control over it. How it works is that every now and then, based on some internal logic, it will collect and remove all instances of classes in memory that do not contain any active references and remove them.

Thus to reduce memory you must ensure that any instances that are no longer needed are not referenced by any of the objects currently active in your model.

To identify these you must use a Java profiler like [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), or some of the free alternatives - see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers) for more.

This will show you exactly what classes are using up all your memory and with some deep diving you should be able to identify who is keeping reference to them.

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. I will look in to JProfiler, and see if it has any effect on the model.  Adding `System.sc();` at `After every Iteration`  allready helps with freeing memory space. I believe based on your reply, I should find references and delete them. A follow-up question though. If a `custom` -class object in ParametersVariation gets added a new row with data from a simulation run, does it (after writing) have a reference to the complete finished simulation?

Comment: It is hard to tell, but it can be the case. Does the custom class keep reference to any object used inside the model? If it just data in the class you are safe. Best practices is to save all the data at the end of an iteration either to a file or to a data only class, and then once the engine gets destroyed all the agents, objects etc will be removed in the next garbage collection run.

Comment: The custom class has a row added after a simulation run in the parameter-variation:
`Customclass row = new Customclass();
row.parameter = root.parameter;
CustomClass_list.add(row);
` is the root.parameter a reference in this case? or will that dissolve after assignment to the parameter in the custom class?

Comment: What is the parameter you are adding?

Comment: I should rephrase that: It is a variable of the total costs the simulation model produces at the end.